# criar um select dentro do while

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho esta consulta:

```
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="font-size: 12px">'.$rows_cursos['DataAprovacao'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="font-size: 12px">'.$rows_cursos['IdTipoProduto'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="font-size: 12px">'.$rows_cursos['IdProduto'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="font-size: 12px"> '.$rows_cursos['Quantidade'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="font-size: 12px"> '.$rows_cursos['IdRequerente'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="font-size: 12px"> '.$rows_cursos['IdDestino'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td style="font-size: 12px"> '.$rows_cursos['Estado'].'</td>';

$tabela1 .= '<td> <select data-qtd3="Fornecedor" style="width:106px" name="Fornecedor[]" id="Fornecedor">
<option></option>
<?php        
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM Fornecedor ORDER BY Fornecedor ASC";
         $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
            echo '<option value="'.$ln['Id'].'">'.$ln['Fornecedor'].'</option>';
         }
      ?>        
</select></td>';

$tabela1 .= '</tr>';

}
```

Só que o select

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <select data-qtd3="Fornecedor" style="width:106px" name="Fornecedor[]" id="Fornecedor">
    <option></option>
    <?php        
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM Fornecedor ORDER BY Fornecedor ASC";
             $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
             while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
                echo '<option value="'.$ln['Id'].'">'.$ln['Fornecedor'].'</option>';
             }
          ?>        
    </select></td>';
```

não está a funcionar. Não retorna os dados dos fornecedores que tenho na tabela da base de dados

Comment: *"Não mostra os tipos de fornecedor que tenho na tabela da base de dados"*, o que isso exatamente quer dizer? Não retorna os dados?

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual, sim já editei a pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente dessa forma:

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <select data-qtd3="Fornecedor" style="width:106px" name="Fornecedor[]" id="Fornecedor">';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Fornecedor ORDER BY Fornecedor ASC";
$qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
    $tabela1 .= '<option value="'.$ln['Id'].'">'.$ln['Fornecedor'].'</option>';
}

$tabela1 .= '</select></td>';
```

Da forma que estava fazendo você estava adicionando um `PHP` com as consultas dentro da string associada a variável `$tabela1`.

Imagino que você estava tentando fazer com que esse trecho do PHP fosse executado quando a variável `$tabela1` fosse impressa. Ao invez disso, procure popular os `options` enquanto está montando a tabela.

Comment: obtive o resultado que pretendia